# Problem with View on change of device orientation

Tags: android, view, orientation

When I go to landscape mode, the bottom two buttons for my activity are not visible.The screen should have automatically converted into scrollable.Do I have to add something to my xml or manifest file?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        > 
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
        />   
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Text in Hindi->"
        />    
    <TextView
        style="@style/PassageStyle"
        android:id="@+id/hindi"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Corresponding Text in English->"
        />  
    <TextView
        style="@style/PassageStyle"
        android:id="@+id/english"
        android:textSize="30dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        />  
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">      
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listen_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dip"
            android:text="@string/listen"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/slow_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Slow"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/listen_Button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/listen_Button"
        />  
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/voice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/voice"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/listen_Button"
            android:layout_below="@id/listen_Button"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_below="@id/slow_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/slow_button"
            />  
    </RelativeLayout>           

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "The screeen should have automatically converted into into scrollable." What makes you think that?

Comment: I have another Listactivity for which it works fine.Any solution to above problem?

Comment: The content of a ListView is inherently scrollable, so that'll be fine. Individual views put one after another in a LinearLayout are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you define your ScrollView?

Try it like this:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

 ... other stuff ...

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have yet to use one, but this should work okay if you wrap the entire xml in a ScrollView.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

if you want that your screen scrollable , you should add a `ScrollView` as a root layout like this :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_heigth="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        > 
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
        />   
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Text in Hindi->"
        />    
    <TextView
        style="@style/PassageStyle"
        android:id="@+id/hindi"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        />
    <TextView  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Corresponding Text in English->"
        />  
    <TextView
        style="@style/PassageStyle"
        android:id="@+id/english"
        android:textSize="30dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        />  
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">      
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/listen_Button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dip"
            android:text="@string/listen"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/slow_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Slow"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/listen_Button"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/listen_Button"
        />  
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/voice"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/voice"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/listen_Button"
            android:layout_below="@id/listen_Button"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/next_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Next"
            android:layout_below="@id/slow_button"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/slow_button"
            />  
    </RelativeLayout>           

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```